# How do I stop ios7 safari form navigation buttons jumping to next form?

Tags: iphone, forms, ios6, ios7, safari

I'm working on a mobile version of a website and testing it in iOS7 Safari. I've noticed that the "next" and "previous" buttons (now just arrows after iOS6) that move you to the next form element actually jumps to the next form when you've reached the last element.

Is there any way of stopping this? It makes this navigation feature unusable especially if you have form elements from 2 different forms close together. I only want these navigation buttons to navigate me from start to finish of one form.

Thanks in advance!